# Rebuild iphone app when updating ad hoc mobile provisioning file?

Tags: iphone

My iphone app is currently in Beta and I am distributing it to beta testers via ad hoc distribution.  If I want to add new users to the beta can I just add their devices and download/distribute a new provisioning profile file, or do I need to rebuild the app with that new app and redistribute both the app and the provisioning profile file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been dealing with this issue and found out [this post](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=149) to be extremelly helpful. Specially this part:

> So my new approach – which has worked
>   well so far – is to create a new Ad
>   Hoc mobile provision file for each
>   beta release.  For example, when I
>   release v1.1 beta 1 to my beta
>   testers, I create a new Ad Hoc mobile
>   provision file called
>   “NRE_1_1_0_beta1.mobileprovision”, and
>   assign every single beta testing
>   device I know of (at that time) to
>   that mobile provision file.  I then
>   build one Ad Hoc copy of the app,
>   signed with this mobile provision
>   file, and send the app and the file to
>   all users.  This requires each user
>   has to install a new mobile provision
>   file each time they receive a new
>   beta, but this makes it much easier to
>   see which provisioning files they have
>   installed on their device.

And, yes, you need to re-build your App once you get a new mobile provision.